# Panel window not scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using following code to create panel but somehow it's scrolling not working:

```
chrome.windows.create({
                url: "panel.html",
                type: "panel",
                focused: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 320
              },
```

How do I make it scrollable?

**Chrome Version**

`40.0.2214.115 (Official Build) on OSX 10.6`

**panel.css**

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffe; }

.error {
  color: #900; }

span.active {
  color: #060; }

span.inactive {
  color: #600; }

.ad video {
  width: 328%;
}
```

**panel.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>This is PANEL</title>
    <link href='assets/stylesheets/panel.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src='assets/javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/javascripts/panel.js'></script>
  </head>
</html>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="title"></div> 
  </header>

  <div class='content'>
    <div class='panel'>
      <div class='ad'>
        <div class='no-activity' style='display: none'> 
Lorem IsPum       
 </div> 
        <div class='skipped' style='display: none'> 
Lorem IsPum
        </div> 
        <div class='activity survey' style='display: none'> 
          <p>Lorem IsPumit?</p> 
          <p> 
            <textarea rows='8' class='comments' placeholder='Enter comments. Enter N/A if you have no comments.'></textarea> 
          </p>  
          <p> 
            <button id='show-next-ad'>Show Next Ad</button> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
      <div class="video-player">    
        <div class="add"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A reminder that `type: "panel"` is disabled unless you switch an experimental flag.

Comment: @Xan Yes it is enabled that's why I am able to see it. I am saying it's not scrolling despite of scrollbars are there

Comment: Which OS, and what's in the `panel.html`?

Comment: @Xan `40.0.2214.115 (Official Build)` on OSX 10.6. it's have a video player and a few buttons.  it's css is `body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffe; }

.error {
  color: #900; }

span.active {
  color: #060; }

span.inactive {
  color: #600; }

.ad video {
  width: 328%;
}`

Comment: Please edit that into the question, it's unreadable in comments.